# Fetch taxonomies by custom post type id array

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I want to find all the taxonomies that match an array of CPT id's.

I have a taxonomy called `location` and I want to find all the locations where they have posts that are equal to my array of post id's e.g. `array(12, 13, 18, 22, 343, 5644)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to find terms of many posts is to use `wp_get_object_terms` function

```
$your_post_ids = array(12, 13, 18, 22, 343, 5644);
$your_taxonomy = 'location' //you can set many as array

$terms = wp_get_object_terms ( $your_post_ids, $your_taxonomy);
```